# DbArithmeticExpression error in linq request

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datetime, request

I'm having an error when I'm trying to request data with Linq and entity framework.
Below, the following:

```
verif = context.DeviceVerifications.Where(d => d.phone == phone 
                && d.securityKey == key 
                && d.validated == 0 
                && (((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - d.createDate)).Minutes <= 30)).FirstOrDefault();
```

The error that shows up is the following: **DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.**
I think that the problem comes from that part of the request **((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - d.createDate)).Minutes <= 30)** but there are the same type on both sides of the comparison.
Does somebody can help me with that ?

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: `(DateTime.Now - d.createDate)` will be of timespan type and so need of explicitely casting it to `Timespan`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether the `((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - d.createDate)).Minutes <= 30)` expression can be correctly converted to a storage query.

I would use the `DbFunctions.DiffMinutes` method

```
verif = context.DeviceVerifications.Where(d => d.phone == phone 
          && d.securityKey == key 
          && d.validated == 0 
          && DbFunctions.DiffMinutes(DateTime.Now, d.createDate) <= 30)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you ! @Lukas Kabrt

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic with DateTime is not supported in Entity Framework, you have to use `DbFunctions.DiffMinutes` instead. According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220102(v=vs.113).aspx), when used as part of a LINQ to Entities query, this method invokes the canonical DiffMinutes EDM function to calculate the number of minutes between two time spans.